# How to model a combination of measurement error and missing data in R and Stan

Tags: r, bayesian, missing-data, measurement-error, stan

**The data**

Consider some simulated data:

```
x <- rep(c(0, 6, 13, 27, 37, 82, 119), 16) # predictor
set.seed(10)
e <- rnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 4) # error
a <- 10 # intercept
b1 <- -0.2 # slopes
b2 <- -0.05
b3 <- -0.3
b4 <- -0.4
y <- a + c(b1, b2, b3, b4) * x + e # linear response
set.seed(15)
sd <- rexp(y, rate = 1) # measurement error
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, sd = sd, # simulated data
                 t = rep(1:4, length.out = length(x)))
```

There are four treatments (`t`) that vary in their linear response (`y`) to `x` (`b1` to `b4`) but do not vary in their intercept (`a`). Each response observation comes with measurement error (`sd`). This can be visualised for clarity, with point-ranges indicating measurement error:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(x = x, y = y, ymin = y - sd, ymax = y + sd)) + 
  facet_grid(~t) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Further consider an additional variable `m` which is causing missing data according to a predictable pattern:

```
m <- ifelse(y < 0, 1, 0) # pattern of missing data

ym <- y # response with missing data
ym[m == 1] <- NA
df$ym <- ym 

sdm <- sd # measurement error with missing data
sdm[m == 1] <- NA
df$sdm <- sdm
```

Whenever `y` crosses a given threshold (in this case 0), data become unavailable. So we have a combination of measurement error and non-random missing data.

**The model**

My preferred method of statistical inference is Bayesian and I am using the `ulam` function of the [rethinking package](https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking), which essentially acts as an R interface to Stan. The case of measurement error described above is fairly standard but the missing data case is peculiar and referred to as **missing not at random**. On page 515 of the second edition of his book *Statistical rethinking*, Richard McElreath describes this case:

> This type of missingness, in which the variable causes its own missing values, is the worst. Unless you know the mechanism that produces the missingness [...], there is little hope. And if you do you [sic] know the mechanism, even then it might be hopeless. Sometimes measurement is all we have. We have to do it better.

This is pretty disheartening but I nonetheless tried implementing a combined measurement error and missing data model, assuming data are missing at random. `ulam` automatically imputes missing observations in the response variable, assuming that they are missing at random, so I simply wrote a measurement error model and left `ulam` to do the missing data imputation.

```
l <- as.list(df[-2:-3]) # ulam() prefers lists
l$N <- nrow(df)

require(rethinking)
mod <- ulam(
  alist(
    # hierarchical likelihood for measurement error
    ym ~ dnorm(mean = y, sd = sdm),
    vector[N]:y ~ dnorm(mean = mu, sd = sigma),
    
    # linear model
    mu <- a + b[t] * x,
    
    # priors
    a ~ dnorm(mean = 10, sd = 1),
    b[t] ~ dnorm(mean = -0.2, sd = 1),
    sigma ~ dexp(rate = 1)
  ), data = l
)
```

Missing observations in `ym` are imputed fine but the model doesn't know what to do with their accompanying missing observations in `sdm`. Here is the error message:

```
Found 40 NA values in ym and attempting imputation.
Found 40 NA values in sdm. Not sure what to do with these, and they might precent the model from running.
Compiling Stan program...
Error: Variable 'sdm' has NA values.
```

A complete cases version of the same model runs fine:

```
l <- as.list(df[-5:-6])
l$N <- nrow(df)

mod.cc <- ulam(
  alist(
    # hierarchical likelihood for measurement error
    y ~ dnorm(mean = ytrue, sd = sd),
    vector[N]:ytrue ~ dnorm(mean = mu, sd = sigma),
    
    # linear model
    mu <- a + b[t] * x,
    
    # priors
    a ~ dnorm(mean = 10, sd = 1),
    b[t] ~ dnorm(mean = -0.2, sd = 1),
    sigma ~ dexp(rate = 1)
  ), data = l, chains = 4, cores = 4
)

precis(mod.cc, depth = 2) # summary of parameter predictions
```

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to implement a combined Bayesian measurement error and missing data model in `ulam` or another R interface to Stan?
2. In the specific case of non-random missing data, is it possible to specify that imputed values ought to be below or above a certain threshold?
3. Is there a way to model a combination of measurement error and missing data in both the explanatory and response variables?

I would appreciate a worked example with code, preferably R implemented in `ulam` but Stan is also welcome.

Comment: Have you tried brms for this? [Here][1] is a link to the relevant vignette and [here][2] a brms version of the Rethinking chapter you refer to.
  [1]: https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/articles/brms_missings.html#combining-measurement-error-and-missing-values-1
  [2]: https://bookdown.org/content/4857/missing-data-and-other-opportunities.html

Comment: Thank you @AngelosAmyntas. With brms I understand less of what Stan actually does in the background so I have avoided it. Since the vignette looks very different to Stan/ulam code, perhaps you could run my MRE in brms in a full answer? If there is a way to then reveal the Stan code brms is using I can perhaps reverse-engineer the ulam code?

Answer (score 0):

I think your model in brms would look like this:

```
library(brms)

df$t = as.factor(df$t)

m = brm(bf(ym|mi(sdm) ~ 1 + x:t), #or ~1+x+x:t for ref. slope and contrasts 
        family = gaussian(),
        prior = c(prior(normal(10, 1), class = Intercept),
                  prior(normal(-.2, 1), class = b),
                  prior(exponential(1), class = sigma)),
        chains = 4,
        iter = 2000,
        cores = 4,
        backend = "cmdstanr", 
        data = df)
summary(m)
stancode(m)
```

It looks like, whether you go with `y` and `sd` or `ym` and `sdm`, brms proceeds without issues...
`stancode()` does what it says on the tin. However brms does a bunch of stuff under the hood so parsing the code is not straightforward (at least it is beyond my ability). If you figure it out and manage to write your own code based on brms's I'd be interested to see it ;)